# Assembly LC3: How to read input without "input a character" being printed to the display?

Tags: assembly, user-input

I'm writing an assembly language program using lc3 and when I run trap x23 (IN) the message "input a character" comes up. I want it to come up saying

`Please enter an integer between 1 and 15:`

but it ends up like this:

`Please enter an integer between 1 and 15:`

```
input a character:
```

Help please

Comment: If that trap isn't doing what you want, maybe you should investigate to see if there's a different trap in the LC3 that does.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the trap IN, it will ask for character input, although you already added your STRINGZ line.
Instead you should just use GETC.